# How to select DOM elements from HTML generated by rails helpers like image_tag?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

I have a javascript constructor that takes a DOM element as an argument, and I'd like to pass in the image generated from this rails helper:

Rails helper:

```
<%= image_tag("/images/" + photo.file_name) %>
```

JS:

```
function Tagger(element) {
     this.photo = element;
     ...
}
```

A solution that doesn't use an external library like jQuery would be great.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Would something like this be sufficient?

```
<%= image_tag("/images/" + photo.file_name, id: 'my_image_id') %>

<script>
  var element = document.getElementById('my_image_id');
   Tagger(element);
</script>
```

**Suggestion:** If you're using Rails I would suggest using jQuery (I know you requested a solution w/o jQuery) as Rails provides it by default and it would make your life a LOT easier.

Comment: If you have multiple images, you could use a `class` instead.